# when an exact binomial confidence interval should be used?

Tags: binomial-distribution, frequentist, exact-test

Is exact binomial confidence interval only appropriate for extremely rare events or extremely frequent events? If so, what are the rule of thumb for the definitions of extremely rare (<0.01?) And is it correct to use simulation to prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be "The exact binomial confidence interval only **available** for extremely rare events or extremely frequent events".

Comment: sorry I did not get it. Why using **available**?

Comment: because if not extreme, it is still take long time to get exact CI using current computer. If you can get exact CI, I think it is better than approximated CI.